# Is overflow-ing possible in CKKS FHE scheme?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

I'm using the [CKKS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421) Fully homomorphic scheme using Microsoft [SEAL](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL), and wonder what will be the result of overflowing a certain floating point variable? Is it even possible to do so?

I found a statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962785/decoding-and-decryption-error-indicators-in-seal#comment96707360_54973270) that overflows can't be detected. If not detected, then what will be the decrypted result?
Thanks!

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors like where the overflow occurs, the circuit, the data, the errors, etc.

Comment: Let's say x*y where x and y are very big values (compared to your parameters). Will the result will be different (assuming an overflow will occur) for x+y?